# On YouTube "Google+" how can I restrict notifications to just people replying to me?

Tags: youtube, google-plus, notifications

On YouTube when I look at notifications I see notifications showing me comments that have nothing to do with me. If they are replying to me fine, otherwise I don't want to know. I am not talking about emails here. These are notifications within `youtube.com`.  How do I stop getting notifications just because somebody commented on a post that I commented on?

[image: notifications]

Comment: @pnuts i'll move the last line above the image 'cos then people will see it and if it's below then they might not

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**  I can't guarantee this works.. Google keeps changing things. e.g. March 2016  google changed my settings to spam me, and i've suddenly started receiving email about comments that have nothing to do with me. The emails can be turned off (there's an unsubscribe link at the end of each email), but will update about notifications.

---

There seem to be two places where notifications are, 
this one seems to work, it's the google+ notifications
https://plus.google.com/u/0/settings

[image]

and there's also this one which may work too
https://www.youtube.com/account_notifications
[image]

But I fixed it by going to the google+ notifications link mentioned, i.e. https://plus.google.com/u/0/settings

To get to the Google+ notifications page you can also go to the bell in the top right

this is what the bell looks like on youtube.com
[image]

this is what the bell looks like on support.google.com
[image]

I am going from youtube.com

Now

Expand the bell and click "google+ notifications"

[image]

A bar like window then appears on the far left.

Now click Settings at the bottom of there

[image]

And you should hopefully be able to get this page

[image]

now looking at that page above, then scroll down expand "Posts" as in the pic below, and you see the pic below,  these checkboxes, and notice I have deselected two of the options, this cuts down on a lot of the junk. So, if somebody refers to me then fine, I get a notification. But I change two of the defaults, because  if somebody just replies to a comment I made, I don't want a notification 'cos lots of people might reply to a comment. And if I participate in a comment thread I don't want to be notified forever after every time somebody comments. These are stupid defaults that I have changed, deselecting them.

[image]